# Angular 5 app sometimes loads old version in browser, I did hashing when building prod, how to load the angular 5 app loads from server?

Tags: angular5

"ng build --output-hashing=all" doesn't solve browser caching issue. Sometimes, browser is loading old version of my angular5 app.

Comment: have you tried clearing the browser's cache?

Comment: I want it to be automatic. I can't clear every user's browser cache, right?

Comment: you are uploading this app on some server? and after you clear the cache does it get the newer version?

Comment: yes, I had to ctrl+f5 hard refresh each time. But after I refresh then close the browser and open another tab, it's still loading old version. Simple refresh fixes it but still older version loads on browser sometimes.